# How can I define operator< for bidirectional iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-keyword, bidirectional

How can I define operator< for bidirectional iterator? ( list::iterator )

(I would like to use list and not vector.)

Comment: Why do you want to use a list and not a vector?

Comment: Why do you want to have `operator<` applied to a list iterator? What is the use case?

Comment: Is this `std::list` or some custom-defined list class of yours?

Answer (score 7):

You can't do it directly, but you can compute `std::distance(x.begin(), it1)` and `std::distance(x.begin(), it2)` and compare those. Given that lists don't have random access, you expect to have to pay the price for such a query by having to traverse the entire list.

---

Edit: This will perform poorly if both iterators are near the end of the list. If you want to get more fancy, you could write some exploring algorithm that moves outwards from both iterators:

```
[ .... <-- it1 --> .... <-- it2 --> .... ]
```

You would basically keep two copies for each, `fwd1`/`rev1` and `fwd2`/`rev2`, and you decrement the `rev*` iterators until you hit `x.begin()` and advance the `fwd*` iterators until you hit `x.end()`. If your iterator pairs are uniformly distributed, this probably has better expected runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible. You might need to walk until `end`, and for that you need to know the `list` of origin, which is not encoded in a `list::iterator`.

(You can make a function object for this purpose, though, which takes the `list` or origin as a constructor argument. Mind you, finding out whether one iterator is less-than another would take O(n) time.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because you'd have to know the start and/or end of the list in order to make such a comparison. Only random access iterators define `operator<`.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing `++(list.end())` is not undefined behaviour and equals `list.end()`, there is a way. But i am not sure of this hypothesis.

If it is valid, you can define a simple algorithm to obtain the result you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is indeed undefined behavior.  It does happen to work on at least one of the major implementations, but that's the best guarentee you'll get.